# Valor por defecto en un select dinámico en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

estoy creando un Select dinámico, y no se cómo añadir un value por defecto para que empiece seleccionado ese por ejemplo tener un value "Seleccionar" mostrado al principio y que después se muestren los elementos que carge en el select. Alguna idea?
Este es mi código Javascript.

```
 //Lista de tableros asignados del usuario.
        Trello.get("members/me/boards", function(cards) {
            $cards.empty();
                $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
                 arrayTableros.push(card.name);
                     arrayIds.push(card.id);
               //Creacion de select.
                 $("<option>")
                .attr("value", card.name)
                .text(card.name)
                .appendTo("#tableros");

                      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes agregar dicha opción antes de agregar los `cards`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
//Lista de tableros asignados del usuario.
Trello.get("members/me/boards", function(cards) {

  // Eliminamos todas las opciones
  $cards.empty();

  // Creación de la opción por defecto.
  $("<option>")
    .attr("value", '')
    .text('- Seleccionar -')
    .appendTo("#tableros");

  // Creas las demas opciones
  $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
    arrayTableros.push(card.name);
    arrayIds.push(card.id);
    
    // Creación de opciones.
    $("<option>")
      .attr("value", card.name)
      .text(card.name)
      .appendTo("#tableros");

});
```